# Generate metadata for parquet files

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, parquet

I have a hive table that is built on top of a load of external parquet files.  Parquet files should be generated by the spark job, but due to setting metadata flag to false they were not generated. I'm wondering if it is possible to restore it in some painless way. The structure of files is like follows:

```
/apps/hive/warehouse/test_db.db/test_table/_SUCCESS
/apps/hive/warehouse/test_db.db/test_table/_common_metadata
/apps/hive/warehouse/test_db.db/test_table/_metadata
/apps/hive/warehouse/test_db.db/test_table/end_date=2016-04-20
/apps/hive/warehouse/test_db.db/test_table/end_date=2016-04-21
/apps/hive/warehouse/test_db.db/test_table/end_date=2016-04-22
/apps/hive/warehouse/test_db.db/test_table/end_date=2016-04-23
/apps/hive/warehouse/test_db.db/test_table/end_date=2016-04-24
/apps/hive/warehouse/test_db.db/test_table/end_date=2016-04-25
/apps/hive/warehouse/test_db.db/test_table/end_date=2016-04-26
/apps/hive/warehouse/test_db.db/test_table/end_date=2016-04-27
/apps/hive/warehouse/test_db.db/test_table/end_date=2016-04-28
/apps/hive/warehouse/test_db.db/test_table/end_date=2016-04-29
/apps/hive/warehouse/test_db.db/test_table/end_date=2016-04-30
```

Let's assume that the file `_metadata` is non-existing or outdated. Is there a way to recreate it via hive command/generate it without having to start the whole spark job?

Comment: @Niemand please edit the question with your latest comment!

Comment: Wouldn't the _metadata be inside of your partitioned folders alongside the .parquet file? Also, can you read the files from a spark shell?

Comment: Yes, some metadata is present in files themselves and yes, they are queryable from both spark shell and hive. It's just I think hive querying is much slower without this particular _metadata file present.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok so here is the drill, metadata can be accessed directly using Parquet tools. You'll need to get the footers for your parquet file first :

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters.{collectionAsScalaIterableConverter, mapAsScalaMapConverter}

import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

val conf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration

def getFooters(conf: Configuration, path: String) = {
  val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
  val footers = ParquetFileReader.readAllFootersInParallel(conf, fs.getFileStatus(new Path(path)))
  footers
}
```

Now you can get your file metadata as followed :

```
def getFileMetadata(conf: Configuration, path: String) = {
  getFooters(conf, path)
    .asScala.map(_.getParquetMetadata.getFileMetaData.getKeyValueMetaData.asScala)
}
```

Now you can get the metadata of your parquet file :

```
getFileMetadata(conf, "/tmp/foo").headOption

// Option[scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String]] =
//   Some(Map(org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.row.metadata ->
//     {"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"long","nullable":false,"metadata":{"foo":"bar"}}
//     {"name":"txt","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}))
```

We can also use extracted footers to write standalone metadata file when needed:

```
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter

def createMetadata(conf: Configuration, path: String) = {
  val footers = getFooters(conf, path)
  ParquetFileWriter.writeMetadataFile(conf, new Path(path), footers)
}
```

I hope this answers your question. You can read more about Spark DataFrames and Metadata on [awesome-spark](https://github.com/awesome-spark)'s [spark-gotchas repo](https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/06_data_preparation.md).